# SQLAlachemy advanced count() query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy with flask. Currently I have 2 models involved in this query:

```
class Actor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('actor_type.id'))
    geo_origin = db.Column(db.String(45))
    type = db.relationship("ActorType")

class ActorType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True)
```

So, I do this query, which works perfectly:

```
actors_by_type = (db.session.query(models.Actor.type_id, func.count(models.Actor.id).label("count")).group_by(models.Actor.type_id)).all()
```

What is the best way to get ActorType.titles instead of ActorType.ids in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i'm not shure about the name of models but it warks fine in my project

```
query = db.session.query(models.ActorType.type_id, func.count(models.Actor.id)) \
       .join(models.Actor) \
       .group_by(models.ActorType.type_id)\
       .all()
```

Comment: Yes its the case but i modified my answer, i hope that help you